# Problem with fs.writeFile in reduce with fetch

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, fetch, reduce

I need some help with this helper I'm writing. For some reason using reduction within an async on a readFile, when trying to write results to a file it won't advance to the next item of the array. However, if I use a console.log, it works just fine.

```
const neatCsv = require('neat-csv');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('./codes.csv', async (err, data) => {
    if (err) { throw err; }

    let baseUrl = 'https://hostname/orders?from=2019-10-21T00:00:00.001Z&to=2019-12-31T23:59:59.000Z&promo=';
    const starterPromise = Promise.resolve(null);
    const promos = await neatCsv(data);
    const logger = (item, result) => console.log(item, result);

    function write (item, result) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            fs.writeFile(`./output/${item.PROMO}.json`, JSON.stringify(result), (err) => {
                if (err) { throw err; }
                console.log(`Wrote file ${item.PROMO}`);
            });
        })
    }

    function asyncFetch(item) {
        console.log(`runTask <---------${item.PROMO}---------`);
        return fetch(`${baseUrl}${item.PROMO}`, { headers: { 'x-apikey': 'xyz' }})
            .then(res => (res.json())
            .then(json => json))
    }

    await promos.reduce(
        (p, item) => p.then(() => asyncFetch(item).then(result => write(item, result))),
        starterPromise
    )
});
```

The csv file is just a basic layout like so..

```
PROMO
12345
56789
98765
...
```

The goal is to iterate over these, make a REST call to get the json results and write those to a file with the name of the current promo, then move to the next, making a new call and saving that one into a different file with its respective code.

In the reduce, if you call logger instead of write, it works fine. Calling write, it just makes the same call over and over and overwriting to the same file, forcing me to kill it. Please help, I'm losing my mind here...

Answer (score 1):

You might have a better time using `async` functions everywhere, the `fs` promises API and a simple while loop to consume the CSV items. Dry-coded, naturally, since I don't have your CSV or API.

(Your original problem is probably due to the fact you don't `resolve`/`reject` in the `write` function, but the reduce hell isn't needed either...)

```
const neatCsv = require("neat-csv");
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const fsp = require("fs").promises;

const logger = (item, result) => console.log(item, result);

const baseUrl = "https://hostname/orders?from=2019-10-21T00:00:00.001Z&to=2019-12-31T23:59:59.000Z&promo=";

async function asyncFetch(item) {
  console.log(`runTask <---------${item.PROMO}---------`);
  const res = await fetch(`${baseUrl}${item.PROMO}`, { headers: { "x-apikey": "xyz" } });
  const json = await res.json();
  return json;
}

async function write(item, result) {
  await fsp.writeFile(`./output/${item.PROMO}.json`, JSON.stringify(result));
  console.log(`Wrote file ${item.PROMO}`);
}

async function process() {
  const data = await fsp.readFile("./codes.csv");
  const promos = await neatCsv(data);
  while (promos.length) {
    const item = promos.shift();
    const result = await asyncFetch(item);
    await write(item, result);
  }
}

process().then(() => {
  console.log("done!");
});
```

---

A version that uses mock data and the JSON Placeholder service, works just fine:

```js
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const fsp = require("fs").promises;

const baseUrl = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments/";

async function asyncFetch(item) {
  console.log(`runTask <---------${item.PROMO}---------`);
  const res = await fetch(`${baseUrl}${item.PROMO}`);
  return await res.json();
}

async function write(item, result) {
  const data = JSON.stringify(result);
  await fsp.writeFile(`./output/${item.PROMO}.json`, data);
  console.log(`Wrote file ${item.PROMO}: ${data}`);
}

async function getItemList() {
  return [
    {PROMO: '193'},
    {PROMO: '197'},
    {PROMO: '256'},
   ];
}

async function process() {
  const promos = await getItemList();
  while (promos.length) {
    const item = promos.shift();
    const result = await asyncFetch(item);
    await write(item, result);
  }
}

process().then(() => {
  console.log("done!");
});
```

Comment: This unfortunately does the same thing. I think it's a race condition now. Trying your code with my api, it does the same thing. When I try it with a mock service (https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1) it works. Just make sure you remove the ${item.PROMO} and header in the fetch. I can't exactly share the api details for security, hope you understand. This is helpful though. One interesting thing though is it never actually completes, it just keeps looping over the length of the promos array.

Comment: If it works with the mock, are you sure you're calling your service correctly?

Comment: 100% positive..it writes the first file and the response is there. Perhaps it’s the size of the response in mine?

Comment: I added another version (using a hard-coded "CSV") and the mock service – I really don't know what to tell you, it works just fine. Which platform are you on, which Node version?

Comment: Thank you. I'm on v10.15.3 at the moment. I found the issue, I had nodemon running to rerun on save. The writeFile was triggering a save causing a reload of the script...stupid. My original script worked just fine actually. It's just interesting that it was working in some writeFile scenarios. Anyways, thank you again for your help!